# How to solve gcc error that prevents package installation with setup.py?

Tags: macos, python, gcc

I'm trying to install package [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/) for Python (on Macos) but I'm getting "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1". I already double-checked all parameters of setup.py file, namely MATLAB_COMMAND,
MATLAB_VERSION,MATLAB_DIR and PLATFORM_DIR. I also have latest Xcode (and gcc is available from command line). 
Any one has any idea on how to solve this?

Here is the full output when trying to install the package with `python setup.py install`

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mlabrawmodule' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_V6_5_OR_LATER=1 -D_V7_3_OR_LATER=1 -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/extern/include -I/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/include/python2.7 -c mlabraw.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/mlabraw.o
In file included from mlabraw.cpp:136:
In file included from /Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: 
      "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
mlabraw.cpp:246:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mxGetPiIsDeprecated'
    lPI = mxGetPi(pArray);
          ^
/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/extern/include/matrix.h:608:17: note: expanded from macro 'mxGetPi'
#define mxGetPi mxGetPiIsDeprecated
                ^
mlabraw.cpp:369:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mxGetPiIsDeprecated'
  lI = mxGetPi(lRetval);
       ^
/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/extern/include/matrix.h:608:17: note: expanded from macro 'mxGetPi'
#define mxGetPi mxGetPiIsDeprecated
                ^
mlabraw.cpp:373:10: warning: 'NPY_CHAR' is deprecated: Use NPY_STRING [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    case PyArray_CHAR:
         ^
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/old_defines.h:49:29: note: expanded
      from macro 'PyArray_CHAR'
#define PyArray_CHAR        NPY_CHAR
                            ^
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:84:30: note: 
      'NPY_CHAR' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
                    NPY_CHAR NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE("Use NPY_STRING"),
                             ^
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:25:50: note: expanded
      from macro 'NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE'
#define NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE(text) __attribute__ ((deprecated (text)))
                                                 ^
mlabraw.cpp:418:10: warning: 'NPY_CHAR' is deprecated: Use NPY_STRING [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    case PyArray_CHAR:
         ^
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/old_defines.h:49:29: note: expanded
      from macro 'PyArray_CHAR'
#define PyArray_CHAR        NPY_CHAR
                            ^
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:84:30: note: 
      'NPY_CHAR' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
                    NPY_CHAR NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE("Use NPY_STRING"),
                             ^
/Users/mactobe/anaconda/envs/SIPLCA27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:25:50: note: expanded
      from macro 'NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE'
#define NPY_ATTR_DEPRECATE(text) __attribute__ ((deprecated (text)))
                                                 ^
mlabraw.cpp:509:37: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
    arp = PyObject_CallMethod(pSrc, "__array__", NULL);
                                    ^
mlabraw.cpp:570:16: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
  char *lStr = "\0"; // "matlab -check_malloc";
               ^
mlabraw.cpp:631:15: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
  char* fmt = "try, %s; MLABRAW_ERROR_=0; catch, MLABRAW_ERROR_=1; end;";
              ^
mlabraw.cpp:662:50: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
    if (NULL == (lArray = _getMatlabVar(lHandle, "MLABRAW_ERROR_")) ) {
                                                 ^
mlabraw.cpp:895:38: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
  mlabraw_error = PyErr_NewException("mlabraw.error", NULL, NULL);
                                     ^
8 warnings and 2 errors generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```